# bind click class selector it fires the function multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, jsapi

I am writing some php code and jquery to make it a bit live. I have a cell table which I click to show a div. The html is something like:

```
<table>
 <tr id="line-157"><td id="cell1-157" class="edit"></td><td id="cell2-157"></td></tr>
 <tr><td id="w_157"></td><td id="p_157"></td></tr>
 <tr id="line-158"><td id="cell1-158" class="edit"></td><td id="cell2-158"></td></tr>
 <tr><td id="w_158"></td><td id="p_158"></td></tr>
 <tr id="line-159"><td id="cell1-159" class="edit"></td><td id="cell2-159"></td></tr>
 <tr><td id="w_159"></td><td id="p_159"></td></tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.edit').bind('click', function() {
                var a = this.id.split('-') ;
                var name_id = a[1] ;
                $('#w_'+name_id).fadeIn();
                $.get('minirpc.php',{
                        subcontrol: 'select_id',
                        id: name_id
                },function(data){
                        $('#w_'+name_id).html(data);
                })
                $.get('minirpc.php',{
                        subcontrol: 'select_pay_id',
                        id: name_id
                },function(data){
                        $('#p_'+name_id).fadeIn();
                        $('#p_'+name_id).html(data);
                })
                return false;
        });
});
```

What I get the callback multiple times instead of one on each click. If I click one time is ok, 2 times it loops 4 times, 3 times it loops 16, and so on...any idea?

EDIT:

reading comments I'm figuring it could be a problem on software architecture, output `data` does contain javascript because minirpc.php calls class_overbooking.php that calls js files. The  files are:

- minirpc.php
- class_overbooking.php
- js/init_overbooking.js
- js/overbooking.js

inside minirpc.php:

```
<?
    include('class_overbooking.php');
    switch($subcontrol){
        case ...
        case quote_select:
        break;
        case quote_pay_id:
        break;
    }    
?>
```

inside class_overbooking.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init_overbooking.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/overbooking.js"></script>
<?
        php class functions mixed jquery
?>
```

inside js/init_overbooking.js:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.13");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
// ![CDATA[
            various sfuff
// ]]
});
```

inside js/overbooking.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   (...)

     $('.edit').live('click', function() {
            var a = this.id.split('-') ;
        var name_id = a[2] ;
        var count = 0 ;
        var start = new Date().getTime();
            $('#w_'+name_id).fadeIn();
        var elapsed1 = new Date().getTime() - start;
                $('#jdebug1').html() ;
                $.get('minirpc.php',{
                        subcontrol: 'quote_select',
                        id: name_id
                },function(data){
                        $('#w_'+name_id).html(data);
                        var elapsed2 = new Date().getTime() - start;
                        $('#jdebug1').append('|('+name_id+')elapsed2:'+elapsed2+'ms ') ;
                });
                $.get('minirpc.php',{
                        subcontrol: 'quote_pay_id',
                        id: name_id
                },function(data){
                        $('#p_'+name_id).fadeIn();
                        $('#p_'+name_id).html(data);
                var elapsed3 = new Date().getTime() - start;
                        $('#jdebug1').append('|('+name_id+')elapsed3:'+elapsed3+'ms ') ;
                });
        return false;
    });

});
```

I also tried with a unique selector class but the problem changing name "edit" into "edit-rev123" is the same.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does `data` contain any JavaScript?

Comment: Does Any of the parent elements of the table have the edit class? Perhaps try a more specific selector for your bind.  Maybe $('table .edit').bind( ... );

Comment: hmm so it is x2 every single click, can you post some sample data so we can test it out

Comment: The point is if I don't include one file inside another as described I can't let jquery working